# What happens if a client connection is killed while holding a lock?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

What happens if a client establishes a transaction, locks a row or table, and the client process crashes before it has a chance to rollback or commit the transaction? What, if anything, does SQL Server do with the transaction?

1. Does SQL Server have a heartbeat mechanism to detect that the socket got killed?
2. Upon detecting that a socket got killed, does SQL Server rollback the transaction automatically? Or does the row/table lock persist (causing other clients to deadlock)?

Please provide authoritative sources to back up your answer.

**UPDATE**: The client process is crashing. I am not talking about someone invoking the [KILL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The session along with the spid attached will be killed/rolled back.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978227/how-to-kill-or-rollback-active-transaction

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

EDIT:

1. I would check your logs to verify, but in essence, the socket would be forcibly closed.

It's not a database issue from what I can see...but do you have an error message you can post to clarify?

Also see [Errors During Transaction Processing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523(v=sql.105).aspx)

> If an error prevents the successful completion of a transaction, SQL
>   Server automatically rolls back the transaction and frees all
>   resources held by the transaction. If the client's network connection
>   to an instance of the Database Engine is broken, any outstanding
>   transactions for the connection are rolled back when the network
>   notifies the instance of the break. **If the client application fails or
>   if the client computer goes down or is restarted, this also breaks the
>   connection, and the instance of the Database Engine rolls back any
>   outstanding connections when the network notifies it of the break.** If
>   the client logs off the application, any outstanding transactions are
>   rolled back

Answer (score 2):

You could test this, like so:

- Open SSMS, Connect to the Server/Database, Open New query
- begin tran , insert into sometable select somevalue
- Open new SSMS window, and run select * from sometable - it should be blocked.
- Open Task Manager and Kill first SSMS process
- Check the results of select in new SSMS window whether the table contains somevalue (it won't, because the transaction got rolled back)

That being said, I have seen cases with SSRS reports where the user closes their browser, but the select query keeps running on the datasource for hours.